# spreadsheet in rails + sharing access to selected users like in google docs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create a single page spreadsheet web application in RAILS  which should be exactly like google doc(should not use google docs API). It should have the following features

1) should scroll from row to row/ cell to cell using arrow keys and also want to copy and paste from cell to cell .

2)Adding , editing and deleting a record and it should contain sharing access for particular users  .

3) If  one user modifies the spreadsheet it should immediately reflect to all user who has permission to view that document.

3) overall it should be in a spreadsheet view.

If there is any other way to solve this solution means can u suggest me?? or please provide me a proper solution..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you find anything to solve this problem ?

Comment: +1 I would like to see this one as well